# scanf() not returning the proper value?

Tags: c

I have a function as part of a larger program to determine the quantity of products sold on each day of the previous week.  Here is the function that performs the case switch:

```
unsigned int switchfn()
{
int productNumber; // product 1 through 5

// only while product 1 through 5 is being entered.
while ((scanf("%d", &productNumber)) != EOF)    {

    // gather product data
    switch (productNumber)  {

    case '1': // product one
        ++productOne;
        break;

    case '2': // product two
        ++productTwo;
        break;

    case '3': // product three
        ++productThree;
        break;

    case '4': // product four
        ++productFour;
        break;

    case '5': // product five
        ++productFive;
        break;

    case '\n': // ignore new line
    case '\t': // ignore tab
    case ' ': // ignore space
        break;

    default: // catch all other characters
        printf("%s", "No such product exists.");
        puts("  Please enter a valid product number.");
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

However, when the program runs, it always jumps to the default, even when entering numbers 1 through 5.  Is this an issue with what scanf() is returning?

Comment: You should check `== 1`, not `!= EOF`.  The function may return `0` if input is entered that isn't a number.

Comment: What are you going to do once you have more than 10 products?

Comment: @M.M: You mean, input like `'\n'`, `'\t'` and `' '`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `%d` will skip those characters

Comment: @M.M: Yes, indeed. That is the problem. That is why the solution is to change away from `%d`, not to change what you compare `scanf` against. That is precisely my point. Glad you got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be getting confused between integers and ASCII digits. You're performing *formatted* extraction, but inspecting `productNumber` as if it were the actual ASCII character found in the input.

Remember, [`'1'` is actually `49`](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Since you want to cover cases like `'\n'` too, read into a `char` with `%c` instead. Then the extraction operation won't perform the formatting conversion for you as it is now, and your character literal comparisons will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `scanf` function is referencing an integer, you merely have to switch your cases to integers:

```
case 1:
 //your logic
break;
case 2:
 //your logic
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Case '1' - at this moment you are asking compiler to check did you enter a character '1' - his ASCII value is 49 and that's the reason why he is just skipping to default case. Try to input " %c"

Comment: I said that twelve hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

scanf("%d", &productNumber) get productNumber is a interger.
But case '1' : '1' is a char and his ASCII value is 49 and so every time you input a interger, there is no match case just skipping to default case. u can input " %c" to get a char.

Comment: Several people have already said this. Your answer does not appear to add any information. Also, please write proper English, which is not written like dis u no innit m8